# what is the best way to cast or handle the date datatype in pyspark

Tags: date, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

Can you please help me to cast the below datatype in pyspark in the better possible way? we cant handle this in the dataframe.

**Input:**

```
Aug 11, 2020 04:34:54.0 PM
```

**to expected output:**

```
2020-08-11 04:34:54:00 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with **`from_unixtime, unix_timestamp`** functions.

**`Example:`**

```
#sample data in dataframe
df.show(10,False)
#+--------------------------+
#|ts                        |
#+--------------------------+
#|Aug 11, 2020 04:34:54.0 PM|
#+--------------------------+

df.withColumn("dt",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("ts"),"MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a"),"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS a")).\
show(10,False)
#+--------------------------+--------------------------+
#|ts                        |dt                        |
#+--------------------------+--------------------------+
#|Aug 11, 2020 04:34:54.0 PM|2020-08-11 04:34:54.000 PM|
#+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

---

If you want new column to be timestamp type then use **`to_timestamp`** function in spark.

```
df.withColumn("dt",to_timestamp(col("ts"),"MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a")).\
show(10,False)
#+--------------------------+-------------------+
#|ts                        |dt                 |
#+--------------------------+-------------------+
#|Aug 11, 2020 04:34:54.0 PM|2020-08-11 16:34:54|
#+--------------------------+-------------------+

df.withColumn("dt",to_timestamp(col("ts"),"MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a")).printSchema()
#root
# |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
# |-- dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS to cast the datatimestamp in pyspark . how to do that .

Comment: @Suganya, could you share some sample data by opening as new question and tag me in the question. I will try to help.